# How can I remove scratches/ coating from my LG mobile camera lens

Tags: cleaning, technology

I recently bought a used LG G2 (T-mobile) from market and later on noticed that it does not takes the photos with expected quality.

I feel that the issue could be possibly because of scratches on Camera lens (coating). I searched on internet and found that we can remove scratches by using toothpaste (with toothbrush?) or some polish. But that solution is particular to removing scratches from lens glass. In my case I see the yellowish coating.

Please suggest How I can get rid of this issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you willing to break the camera altogether in an attempt to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard first rule of cleaning optics is: Don't!

Cleaning with an abrasive like toothpaste is far more likely to render the lens evenly "milky" due to putting fine scratches all over it.  Further, the "lens" you can touch is actually an optical flat cover that protects the actual lens, and in many phones and tablets it's made of synthetic sapphire -- so the only thing likely to be scratched, or vulnerable to your polishing attempts (short of using powdered diamond on an optical lap) is the coating.

It's unlikely that any photo quality issues you may see are due to individual scratches on the cover, in any case; it's far more likely that the focusing mechanism (probably a piezoelectric unit behind the sensor chip) is malfunctioning, a setting in the camera software is wrong, or there's junk on the sensor itself.

TL:DR; you're more likely to make it worse than better if you try to polish the lens cover.

Comment: I agree, with stuff like this I much rather just buy the spare part and replace it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a new mobile and you recently bought it, I suggest you to take it to the service center. Any stunt you may pull may result in breaking your warranty or guarantee. If the guarantee/ warranty period is over, then what you've heard is an acceptable method to clean camera lenses. Toothpaste can be used. But be careful to follow the correct steps. [Try this link](http://www.cultofandroid.com/65721/dab-toothpaste-need-remove-scratches-htc-one-m8s-camera-lens/). However, I advice you not to go ahead with it unless you are certain and very confident. Any actions you perform is strictly under your own responsibility and nobody else will take liability for your actions. So be very careful. Cheers

Comment: "I recently bought a used LG G2 (T-mobile) from market" please read the question first....

Comment: That is why I have mentioned it in my answer. Read the answer completely.

Comment: I read it, and half of it its unnecessary

Comment: That is your personal opinion. Let's leave it to the OP. This is for him. And if he doesn't find it useful, then it probably isn't.